# JDK warning in Jenkins 2.121.3 LTS version

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have upgraded my jenkins from 2.89.4 to 2.121.3 version
I am seeing a very long list of warnings in logs. Not sure how to resolve it.

```
WARNING: Could not find dependency jdk-tool of gerrit-code-review
Sep 07, 2018 8:22:03 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin getNeededDependencies
WARNING: Could not find dependency jdk-tool of git-bisect
Sep 07, 2018 8:22:03 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin getNeededDependencies
WARNING: Could not find dependency jdk-tool of git-bisect
Sep 07, 2018 8:22:03 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin getNeededDependencies
WARNING: Could not find dependency jdk-tool of git-notes
Sep 07, 2018 8:22:03 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin getNeededDependencies
WARNING: Could not find dependency jdk-tool of ruby-runtime
Sep 07, 2018 8:22:03 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin getNeededDependencies
WARNING: Could not find dependency jdk-tool of git-notes
Sep 07, 2018 8:22:03 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin getNeededDependencies
WARNING: Could not find dependency jdk-tool of ruby-runtime
Sep 07, 2018 8:22:03 AM hudson.model.UpdateSite$Plugin getNeededDependencies
WARNING: Could not find dependency jdk-tool of git-prebuildmerge-trait
```